# Solving a ranking problem in a purely functional way using groovy

Tags: groovy, functional-programming, ranking

I have solved a problem that ranks fruits by the number of votes. Unfortunately, I want to solve the problem in a purely functional way without mutating the rankPosition variable. Here is my solution:

```
  def fruits=[
 [name:'apple',       votes:120 , ranking:null ],
 [name:'banana',      votes:200,  ranking: null],
 [name:'apricot',     votes:66,   ranking:null ],
 [name:'pear',        votes:84,   ranking:null],
 [name:'kiwi',        votes:77,   ranking:null],
 [name:'plum',        votes:66,   ranking:null],
 [name:'berry',       votes:120,  ranking:null],
 [name:'pineapple',   votes:50,   ranking:null],
 [name:'grapes',      votes:200,  ranking:null]
```

]

```
    def rankPosition= 1
    def groupedByVotes = fruits.groupBy {it.votes }

     println "Ratings $groupedByVotes"

    def finalResults=groupedByVotes.sort().each { votes, items ->

        items.each { it.ranking = rankPosition }

        rankPosition += items.size()
    } 

    println "Final Results are $finalResults"
```

How can I solve this problem without having to declare a rankingPosition variable external to the closure and mutating its state. Please notes that this solution works but I have since learned that I shouldn't be doing it this way. 
I want to be able to fill the rankings with the correct ranking. The inject function does an accumulation but I don't know how to combine it in a way to also set the ranking with the value accumulated in the inject.

I am simply stuck, just don't seem to be able to reason about this one. My attempt below to use inject, simply did not work. Maybe there isn't a way to do this in a purely functional way, better thsn my attempt.

```
def res= groupedByVotes.collectEntries{votes, list1->
println "list class $list1"
def r= list1.inject(0){acc,l-> acc+l.size()}
 list1.each{it.ranking=r}
 println "$r"
 [(votes): list1]
} 
println "$res"
```

I anyone can then I would appreciate your solution or just assume my attempt is the most realistic way of solving this one.

Comment: I don't know groovy, but if it's a functional language, it will have a `reduce`/`fold` function. Change the `each` to `reduce`, then make `rankPosition` the accumulator of the reduction.

Comment: Groovys *reduce* is `inject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pure functional solution. It leaves the initial map of maps unchanged and produces a new one:

```
def results = groupedByVotes.sort().inject(new Tuple(1, [:]), { acc, entry ->
    def newRank = acc[0] + entry.value.size()
    def newValue = entry.value.collect { [*:it, ranking:acc[0]] }
    return new Tuple(newRank, [*:acc[1], (entry.key):newValue] )
})
finalResults = results[1]
```

Comment: Thank you Donat, this is truly an excelllent solution. Really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def results = groupedByVotes.sort()
    .inject(new Tuple(1, []), { acc, entry ->
        entry.value.each { it.ranking = acc[0] }
        return new Tuple(acc[0] + entry.value.size(), acc[1] << entry.value)
    })

finalResults = results[1]
```

In each step of the folding (done by `.inject(...)`) you have a `Tuple` containing the next rank and the partial list that has been computed so far. As a final step you extract the result list from the `Tuple`. But this converts the map to a list.

This solution is even simpler because it is not necessary to make a new collection if you modify the old one in place, and it preserves the map:

```
def finalResults = groupedByVotes.sort()
finalResults.inject(1, { acc, entry ->
    entry.value.each { it.ranking = acc }
    return acc + entry.value.size()
})
```

But both solutions are not really functional. Real functional code treats all values as if they were immutable. See my other answer (coming) for a real functional solution.

Comment: Thanks Donat, I wlll try your solution. I have eventually found a solution which I was going to post. Thank you very much, really appreciated, and it worked!! Much better than mine.

Comment: I do not understanding how the ranking is inserted, I do not see anywhere how that is done.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation for `inject`. This method is like `fold` in many functional languages. It takes two parameters: The first is the start value (the result when the list is empty). The second is a method which computes from an intermediate result and one list element a new intermediate result. This will be done for each list element. The result will be something like `method(method(method(start, list[0]), list[1]), list[2])` when there are three elements in the list.

Comment: I understand the inject part it is how entry.value.ranking=calculatedRanking is applied

Comment: I have found it doesn't actually set the ranks like I thought. It calculates the final ranking value. I'm sorry I did not explain myself properly.

Comment: @BreenDeen Sorry, I had forgotten the line above the line beginning with return, but this is not the simplest solution. I will add another solution. And these two solutions are not really functional because they modify the map of lists in place. So i will add another answer without this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I probably did not explain very well what I was trying to achieve. After calculating the rank, I wanted the values inserted for the respective elements in the list. Here is what I came up with:

```
  def sortedFruits= fruits.sort{f1, f2 -> f1.votes <=> f2.votes}

  (0..sortedFruits.size()-1)
   .each{ i ->
    if(i==0){
    sortedFruits.get(i).ranking=1
    }else if(sortedFruits.get(i-1).votes==sortedFruits.get(i).votes){
      sortedFruits.get(i).ranking=i
   }else{
    sortedFruits.get(i).ranking=i+1
  }
   if(i<sortedFruits.size()){
     def f= sortedFruits.get(i)
      println "${f}"
  }

}

 println "Sorted Fruits are $sortedFruits"
```

The final result looks like
Sorted Fruits are [[name:lemons, votes:20, ranking:1], [name:guava, votes:20, ranking:1], 
    [name:pineapple, votes:50, ranking:3], [name:apricot, votes:66, ranking:4], [
    name:plum, votes:66, ranking:4] etc.